# What are the implications of extracting a canine tooth without an immediate implant?

Tags: risks, tooth-extraction, implant, cracked-broken-tooth

I have a canine that hurts even after a root canal; the evidence points towards a crack in the tooth. It looks like I'll need it extracted, but I'm not sure I can afford getting an immediate implant. Given that it's an anchor tooth, what's the possibility of bone loss or other implications if I wait 5 months before getting the implant? Is there much risk in getting extracted now and waiting it to heal before starting the implant? Thanks so much!